# Roslyn MSBuild workspace adds extra trailing slash?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, roslyn, msbuild-task

So my setup is:

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, v. 2.7.0
....
Microsoft.Build, v. 15.6.85

This is a web app.

I have the following code:

```
var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(filePath).Result;
```

Basically, I want to load a local (local to the server) solution and do some analysis on it.

However, loading it seems to cause issues, like:

Msbuild failed when processing the file 'C:\Projects\Project.csproj' with message:

> The "RazorCodeGen" task could not be instantiated from the assembly
>   "C:\Projects\packages\RazorGenerator.MsBuild.2.4.1\build\\..\tools\RazorGenerator.MsBuild.dll".
>   Please verify the task assembly has been built using the same version
>   of the Microsoft.Build.Framework assembly as the one installed on your
>   computer and that your host application is not missing a binding
>   redirect for Microsoft.Build.Framework. Unable to cast object of type
>   'RazorGenerator.MsBuild.RazorCodeGen' to type
>   'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask'.

Note that the path in the error message contains:
build\\..\tools.

Looks like there is a \\ in the path.

1. Removing the extra trailing slash allows me to open the task (so it
   does exist and is there).
2. Opening and building the solution with Visual Studio 2017 community
   edition works.
3. Building the solution with MSBuild (v. 15.0) works as well.

I already added the binding redirects from MSBuild.exe.config to my application Web.Config.

**Update:**

Just wrote a few lines of code, trying to build the solution with Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager and have the same error. So it seems the issues is in MSBuild rather than Roslyn / MSBuildWorkspace.

Answer (score 0):

> Roslyn MSBuild workspace adds extra trailing slash?

After checking the `Microsoft.Build.Framework` assembly used in the project [RazorGenerator.MsBuild](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator/blob/master/RazorGenerator.MsBuild/RazorGenerator.MsBuild.csproj), will find it was compiled against an old version of MSBuild 4.0. this error arises when the application can't handle multiple different definitions of `ITask` (the new one from your Microsoft.Build, v. 15.6.85).

To resolve this issue, you can try to default `Microsoft.Build.Framework` references v4.0 or add [Binding Redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Check [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/653) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to be the case, I already have the binding redirects in the web.config of the web app that opens the solution and also - the double slash - \\..\ is what seems to make the difference between file being found and not being found. I am new to MSBuild / Roslyn so please excuse me if I'm missing something important here.

Comment: Just got Roslyn from Github, did a basic test and opened the same  solution, it only shows "\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets: (134, 9): Could not find rule set file "AllRules.ruleset"." which I think should be fine. So it's either the latest version of Roslyn (cloned it yesterday) is working fine or it has something to do with the fact that I am opening the solution from web or maybe something with the binding redirects. Not sure yet. Still trying to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score -3):

When accessing from directory:
`\\local-pc\Bases\System under development\ERP` - does not work.

But when I put the project and browse the directory:
`D:\Bases\System under Development\ERP\System` - works

My `D:` is mapped to `local-pc`.

It means RazorCodeGen is looking for a location and the project has been opened by another location.